# Search and delete for a range of lines in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I could not extract out a range of lines which needs to be deleted in the following example. The regular expression for $end_pattern seems not matching.

Please let me know what I am missing. Thanks much

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$begin_pattern = 'Fac.*Begin-to-search';
$end_pattern   = 'Mix.*End-to-search';

open(IN, "Input.txt") || die "Can't open file!\n";
my @lines = <IN>;
foreach $line (@lines) {
    $line =~ s/^\s+//; #remove leading spaces
    $line =~ s/\s+$//; #remove trailing spaces

    if ($line =~ /$begin_pattern ... $end_pattern/) {
       print "$line\n";
    }

    # Next, delete this range of lines
}

"Input.txt" file listed below:
-----------
 something for storing 0
No. of blocks : 0
         Filt  Nothing                  Nothing
     Fac           Y    0    Mix    0      Mix   Mix  0                  Begin-to-search
96   Fac           Y    0    60     0      900   60   0                  0                   0
806  Fac           Y    0    0      0      0     0    0                  0                   0  
     Fac A|B|C|D   Y    11   0      0      0     0    0
340  Fac A|B|C|D   Y    11   0      0      0     0    0                  0                   0
     Mix M         Y    11   Mix    Mix    0     Mix  0                  End-to-search
573  Wrn A|B|C|D   Y    11   0      0      0     0    0                  0                   0
Mix M         Y    11   60     Mix    0     60   0                  ware
```

---

Revised code with warnings: (see question below)

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $begin_pattern = 'Fac.*Begin-to-search';
my $end_pattern   = 'Mix.*End-to-search';
open(IN, "Input.txt") || die "Can't open file!\n";

my @lines = <IN>;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    $line =~ s/^\s+//;
    $line =~ s/\s+$//;

    if(defined $line) { print "\$line is initialized\n"; }
    else { print "\$line is uninitialized\n"; }

    if ($line =~ /$begin_pattern/ ... /$end_pattern/) {
       print "$line";
    }

    if ($line =~ /$end_pattern/) {
        last;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) is used as

```
if ($line =~ /$begin_pattern/ .. $line =~ /$end_pattern/)
```

so you are only missing `$line =~` for the second condition.

It's better to use the [qr operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) for regex, and you can use the [`$_` variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) effectively here

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $begin_pattern = qr/Fac.*Begin-to-search/;
my $end_pattern   = qr/Mix.*End-to-search/;

my $file = 'Input.txt';    
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (<$fh>) 
{
    s/^\s+//;   
    s/\s+$//;

    if (/$begin_pattern/ .. /$end_pattern/) {
        print;
    }
}
close $fh;
```

This prints only the lines between markers matched by regexes

```
     Fac           Y    0    Mix    0      Mix   Mix  0                  Begin-to-search
96   Fac           Y    0    60     0      900   60   0                  0                   0
806  Fac           Y    0    0      0      0     0    0                  0                   0  
     Fac A|B|C|D   Y    11   0      0      0     0    0
340  Fac A|B|C|D   Y    11   0      0      0     0    0                  0                   0
     Mix M         Y    11   Mix    Mix    0     Mix  0                  End-to-search
```

A few other notes

- Please *always* start with `use warnings;` and `use strict;`
- The three-argument `open` is recommended, and better
- When you print error messages use [$! variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables) to see the actual message
- Process files line-by-line unless there is a specific reason to read all lines first

---

This note mostly aggregates comments, explaining the behavior of the code in the question.

The line (corrected from the original, in the edit of the question)

```
if ($line =~ /$begin_pattern/ ... /$end_pattern/)
```

is really

```
if ($line =~ /$begin_pattern/ ... $_ =~ /$end_pattern/)
```

since `/.../` always matches against `$_`, its default.

However, in the loop `foreach my $line (@lines)` we introduce a lexical variable to iterate (`$line` aliases elements) and then we *do not get the `$_`; it is not defined for the loop*. So the second pattern never matches, as observed.

Note that `$_` from a higher scope -- say, some outer loop -- may still be seen inside the loop.

The solution is to either enable the use of `$_` as topicalizer by `foreach (@lines)` (or as in the answer, `while (<$fh>)`, reading line by line) and then use

```
if (/$begin_pattern/ .. /$end_pattern/)
```

where matches are against `$_`,  or to set the variable and use it in both conditions

```
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    # ...
    if ($line =~ /$begin_pattern/ ... $line =~ /$end_pattern/)
```

Please note that `..` and `...` actually differ a little. See linked documentation.

One can in fact also set `$_` (to `$line`) at the beginning of the loop and then the posted code would work as it stands. This would clearly be awkward, to say the least.

Comment: Ah, I missed the matching ending forward slash. Thanks much.
2 questions for the additional code above:
Question 1) Why it continues to print if I don't have the last 3 lines?
    if ($line =~ /$end_pattern/) {
        last;
    }

Question 2) Wonder where the warning "Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match ..." comes from with strict turned on.

Comment: @user1972031 The `if ($line =~ /$beg/ ... /$end/)` is taken as `if ($line =~ /$beg/ .. $_ =~ /$end/)`.  However, once a variable is used in `while (my $line = <$fh>)` (or in `foreach`) then `$_` _is not set_; if we introduce a lexical for the loop variable we don't get `$_`.  So it is "uninitialized" in the second condition, which explains (1) since that second condition never matches (is never true) so the range operator never becomes false, and it keeps printing.  This is also directly (2).

Comment: @user1972031  The key is that the range operator keeps the state: once the first condition evaluates true, the operator "remembers" that and is true -- until the second condition becomes true, at which point the whole operator returns false.  (Of course, there is also a bit of syntax and `$_` behavior that are involved.)

Comment: `if ($line =~ /$beg/ .. $_ =~ /$end/)` Isn't $line and $_ the same thing?
How can the code tell which one is which if it interprets it as:
`if ($line =~ /$beg/ .. $_ =~ /$end/)` ?

Comment: @user1972031  That's the problem -- there is no `$_`.  When we say `while (<$fh>)` then `$_` is the line from file, but when we say `while (my $var = <$fh>)` _then `$_` is not defined_.  That's just how it works, since we used our own variable the deal with having `$_` is off and we don't get it.  Now, in the syntax `if ($line =~ /beg/ .. /end/)` the second regex doesn't have a variable to match (it's just `/end/`) so it uses the default, `$_ =~ /end/`.  So we end up with `if ($line =~ /beg/ .. $_ =~ /end/)`, where, alas, `$_` isn't defined (if we used a variable for the loop).

Comment: @user1972031  So we have to either do `while (my $line = <$fh>) { if ($line =~ /beg/ .. $line =~ /end/) { ...} }`, OR `while (<$fh>) { if (/beg/ .. /end/) { ...} }`.  In the second case both regex are matched against `$_` (by default), which is defined (since we don't use our own variable in `while`).

Comment: @user1972031  Try it.  Say, `@ary = qw(one beg some other end two); for (@ary) { say if /beg/ .. /end/; }`.  This prints things from `beg` to `end`.  Now try with `for my $var (@ary) { say if /beg/ .. /end/ }` -- it warns you about `Use of unitialized value $_ in pattern match ...` since it's trying to match regex against `$_`, but this is not defined since I used `$var` for the loop variable.  Now try inside the loop `say if $var =~ /beg/ .. $var =~ /end/` -- it works fine.

Comment: @user1972031  Finally, now try this `for my $var (@ary) { $_ = 'other';  say if $var =~ /beg/ .. /other/ }`.  Now when `/other/` regex does `$_ =~ /other/` the `$_` _is defined_, since we set it. And it matches on `other`, the range op is false, and it stops printing after it.

Comment: @user1972031  You need `use feature qw(say);` for `say` (like `print` but adds the newline), or in a one-liner use `-E` instead of `-e` (like `perl -E'say "hello"'`).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You try to match everything between `$begin_pattern` and `$end_pattern`, but you read the file line by line, so it never matches cause these patterns don't appear on the same line.

Check for the each pattern separately, remember whether you're in the block of lines you want, and then print.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $begin_pattern = 'Fac.*Begin-to-search';
my $end_pattern = 'Mix.*End-to-search';

my $in_block = 0;
foreach my $line (<DATA>) {
    $line =~ s/^\s+//; #remove leading spaces
    $line =~ s/\s+$//; #remove trailing spaces

    $in_block = 1 if ($line =~ m/$begin_pattern/);
    $in_block = 0 if ($line =~ m/$end_pattern/);
    print "$line\n" if ($in_block);
}

__DATA__
 something for storing 0
No. of blocks : 0
         Filt  Nothing                  Nothing
     Fac           Y    0    Mix    0      Mix   Mix  0                  Begin-to-search
96   Fac           Y    0    60     0      900   60   0                  0                   0
806  Fac           Y    0    0      0      0     0    0                  0                   0  
     Fac A|B|C|D   Y    11   0      0      0     0    0
340  Fac A|B|C|D   Y    11   0      0      0     0    0                  0                   0
     Mix M         Y    11   Mix    Mix    0     Mix  0                  End-to-search
573  Wrn A|B|C|D   Y    11   0      0      0     0    0                  0                   0
Mix M         Y    11   60     Mix    0     60   0                  ware
```

Comment: Each of the patterns does appear on a line. (First line of the table and the line before the last.)

Comment: If you meant that _both_ patterns need to be on the same line, this isn't the case: the range operator keeps the state -- it is true once it finds the first pattern, until (after) the second one.

Comment: Thanks Robert, for the trick of not displaying the last pattern line. 
(I definitely missed the matching forward slash; thus the error.)